# Title of book about world of public thoughts where boy discovers silence?

Tags: story-identification

I have not actually read this book, but had looked up the plot with the intention of eventually reading it; unfortunately, I forgot the title.

The book takes place in the future, I believe on another planet where colonists have recently settled. However, there was a disease or something else in the environment of the planet that resulted in everyone's thoughts becoming uncontrollably public. However, a boy accidentally discovers a lone patch of silence somehow generated by a girl. The fact that he discovered silence was unacceptable, and as such he had to escape from his community. Furthermore, I think his community was exclusively male- the females might have been wiped out by the same thing that caused the forced telepathy.

I'm not entirely sure when this could have been written, but I feel that it is a more modern book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [Chaos Walking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_Walking) series by Patrick Ness, specifically the first novel in the series, **The Knife of Never Letting Go**.

> Chaos Walking is a young adult science fiction series by the U.S.-born
>   British novelist Patrick Ness. **It is set in a dystopian world where
>   all living creatures can hear each other's thoughts in a stream of
>   images, words, and sounds called Noise.** The series is named after a
>   line in the first book: "The Noise is a man unfiltered, and without a
>   filter, a man is just chaos walking." The series consists of a trilogy
>   of novels and three short stories.
>
> The three novels feature two adolescents, Todd Hewitt and Viola Eade,
>   who encounter various moral issues and high stakes as the planet
>   around them erupts into war. **The Knife of Never Letting Go (2008)
>   begins with Todd being forced to flee his town after discovering a
>   patch of silence, free of Noise.**

[image]