# What book trilogy is this?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

The first book is about a boy living in an all male community on Mars. It talks about how all the women died from a Martian disease. Then a girl crashes a stolen space ship near the town and the boy finds her (I can't remember their names). I'm pretty sure the girl wouldn't talk or they didn't speak the same language. The town then freaks (I don't remember why) and they kill the boys older brother. The boy and girl then escape the town and have to run to another settlement (which the boy didn't even know about). Eventually, somewhere in the trilogy, they find out that the men in the village killed all of the women for crazy reason. They go to war in the last book (again can't remember why.)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Title of book about world of public thoughts where boy discovers silence?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172893/title-of-book-about-world-of-public-thoughts-where-boy-discovers-silence)

Comment: Voting to leave open, as there is no accepted answer yet.

Answer (score 3):

That's *[The Knife of Never Letting Go](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2118745.The_Knife_of_Never_Letting_Go)*, first book of the *Chaos Walking Trilogy*, by Patrick Ness, being adapted into a film, "Chaos Walking", starring Daisy Ridley. The planet isn't Mars though. Those are all plot points from the book.

> Prentisstown isn't like other towns. Everyone can hear everyone else's thoughts in an overwhelming, never-ending stream of Noise. Just a month away from the birthday that will make him a man, Todd and his dog, Manchee -- whose thoughts Todd can hear too, whether he wants to or not -- stumble upon an area of complete silence. They find that in a town where privacy is impossible, something terrible has been hidden -- a secret so awful that Todd and Manchee must run for their lives.

From the second book, *[The Ask and the Answer](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6043849-the-ask-and-the-answer)*:

> Fleeing before a relentless army, Todd has carried a desperately wounded Viola right into the hands of their worst enemy, Mayor Prentiss. Immediately separated from Viola and imprisoned, Todd is forced to learn the ways of the Mayor's new order. But what secrets are hiding just outside of town? And where is Viola? Is she even still alive? And who are the mysterious Answer? And then, one day, the bombs begin to explode...

From the third, *[Monsters of Men](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7540092-monsters-of-men)*:

> Three armies march on New Prentisstown, each one intent on destroying the others. Todd and Viola are caught in the middle, with no chance of escape. As the battles commence, how can they hope to stop the fighting? How can there ever be peace when they're so hopelessly outnumbered? And if war makes monsters of men, what terrible choices await?